# R - how to loop through multiple regex rules instead of an OR statement?

Tags: r, regex, loops

I have a text filed with different types of date formats and its id`s. I need to extract all the strings using regex.

```
df <- data.frame(id=1:8,text=c("deficit based on wage statement 7/14/ to 7/17/2015.",
                    "Deficit Due: $1205.73 -$879.63= $326.10 x 70%=$228.2.",
                    "Deficit Due for 12 wks pd - 7/14/15 thru 10/5/15;Deficit due to wage,", 
                    "statement: 4/22/15 thru 5/12/15,depos transcript 7/10/15 for 7/8/15 depos,",
                    "difference owed for 4/25/15-5/22/15 10-29-99 Feb. 25, 2009,",
                    "tpd 4:30:2015 - 5:22:2015--09/26/99, 7-14 1.3.99, 1.3.1999,",
                    "Medical TREATMENT DATES:  6/30/2015 -  30/06/2015 09/26/1999,",
                    "4/25/15-5/22/15,Medical 2010-01-29 **2010-01-30 February25,2009, February 25, 2009"))
```

So far, I have created regex using multiple OR statements.

```
    #Different string patterns
#all day formats
day<-c(31:1,"01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09")
day_p<-paste(day,collapse = "|")
day_p <- paste0("(",day_p,")")

#all month formats
month<-c(12:1,"01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09")
month_p<-paste(month,collapse="|")
month_p <- paste0("(",month_p,")")

#all year 4 digit formats
year<-"\\d{4}"
year_p<-paste(year,collapse="|")
year_p <- paste0("(",year_p,")")

#all year 2 digit formats
year_i<-"\\d{2}"
year_i_p<-paste(year_i,collapse="|")
year_i_p <- paste0("(",year_i_p,")")

#all seperator symbol
symbol_p<-paste(c("\\.","\\|","\\/","\\-","\\:","\\,"),collapse="|")
symbol_p <- paste0("(",symbol_p,")")


patterns<-paste0("(",month_p,symbol_p,day_p,symbol_p,year_p,")","|",
             "(",day_p,symbol_p,month_p,symbol_p,year_p,")","|",
             "(",year_p,symbol_p,month_p,symbol_p,day_p,")","|",
             "(",month_p,symbol_p,day_p,symbol_p,year_i_p,")","|",
             "(",day_p,symbol_p,month_p,symbol_p,year_i_p,")","|",
             "(",year_i_p,symbol_p,month_p,symbol_p,day_p,")","|",
             "(",month_p,"\\-",day_p,")","|",
             "(",day_p,"\\-",month_p,")","|",
             "(",month_p,"\\/",day_p,")","|",
             "(",day_p,"\\/",month_p,")")

#String extaction
extract= str_extract_all(df$text,patterns)
```

Is there an approach to put all the regex rules in a data frame, name each rule and do a string extraction?

```
#regex patterns in a data frame 
df_patterns<-data.frame(pattern=c(paste0("(",month_p,symbol_p,day_p,symbol_p,year_p,")"),
                                  paste0("(",day_p,symbol_p,month_p,symbol_p,year_p,")")),
                        rule=c(1,2))
```

The output data frame should include the extraction values and the rule which triggered its extraction.

```
#output data frame
output<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3,3),string=c("7/14","7/17/2015",NA,"7/14/15","10/5/15"),rule=c(9,1,NA,2,3))
```

Comment: I wonder how you are trying to differentiate "month/day/year_i" vs "day/month/year_i" vs "year_i/month/day" and so on.  They look all the same in terms of the string patterns.

Comment: Why do you you need to track which Regex returns the match? You can return all the same matches with a much simpler expression: `unlist(regmatches(df$text,gregexpr("(?m)\\d+[/-]\\d+[/-]\\d*",df$text,perl=TRUE)))`

Comment: @useR To keep the case simple, strings can be referred to as dates in this case.

Comment: My first example misses the `.`'s, but you get the idea.

Comment: @Mako212 no need `(?m)`

Comment: @useR Thanks. This one matches the dots and colon formats too `unlist(regmatches(df$text,gregexpr("(?<=\\s|[-*])\\d+[.:/-]\\d+[.:/-]\\d*",df$text,perl=T)))`

Comment: Last one `unlist(regmatches(df$text,gregexpr("(?<=\\s|[-*]|^)\\d+[.:/-]\\d+[.:/-]{0,1}\\d*",df$text,perl=T)))`

Comment: @Mako212 This is a case which includes multiples rules. Holiday dates, month granularity, decade granularity etc. Ultimately, if the rule fails, we would like to know which rule caused the issue.

Comment: @x1carbon Getting bad matches is one thing, but if a rule fails, that means you're not going to return a match when you should, means your Regex rule set as a whole failed - so it doesn't really help you most of the time. If you're constantly getting bad matches, you should write more specific Regex.

Comment: @x1carbon well you cant know what rule caused a non-match if it couldn't detect it in the first place. If it did, it wouldn't be a fail.

Answer (score 1):

`stringr` has a function called `str_match_all` that can extract all matches as well as return the capture groups that matched in separate columns. This is convenient for this question since you can name the capture groups and associate them to each column of output from `str_match_all`:

```
#Different string patterns
#all day formats
day_p <- "[0-3]?[0-9]"

#all month formats
month_p <- "[0-1]?[0-9]"

#all year 4 digit formats
year_p <- "\\d{4}"

#all year 2 digit formats
year_i_p <- "\\d{2}"

#all seperator symbol
symbol_p <- "[-/:.]"

# Patterns to match structured as combination of capture groups
patterns<-paste0("(",month_p,symbol_p,day_p,symbol_p,year_p,")","|",
                 "(",day_p,symbol_p,month_p,symbol_p,year_p,")","|",
                 "(",year_p,symbol_p,month_p,symbol_p,day_p,")","|",
                 "(",month_p,symbol_p,day_p,symbol_p,year_i_p,")","|",
                 "(",day_p,symbol_p,month_p,symbol_p,year_i_p,")","|",
                 "(",year_i_p,symbol_p,month_p,symbol_p,day_p,")","|",
                 "(",month_p,"[-]",day_p,")","|",
                 "(",day_p,"[-]",month_p,")","|",
                 "(",month_p,"[/]",day_p,")","|",
                 "(",day_p,"[/]",month_p,")","|",
                 "(", "\\w+[.]?[\\s]?\\d+[,]\\s?",year_p,")")

# Name the capture groups
rule_names = c("MDYYYY", "DMYYYY", 
               "YYYYMD", "MDYY", 
               "DMYY", "YYMD", 
               "MD_dash", "DM_dash", 
               "MD_slash", "DM_slash",
               "MDYYYY_word")

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
df$text %>%
  str_match_all(patterns) %>%
  map2(df$id, function(x, y){
    if(nrow(x) == 0){
      x = rbind(x, NA)
    }
    data.frame(id = y, x)
  }) %>%
  do.call(rbind, .) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(X2:X11), funs(ifelse(!is.na(.), 1, NA))) %>%
  setNames(c("id", "string", rule_names)) %>%
  gather(rule, value, -id, -string) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  arrange(id)
```

**Notes:**

1. This final part does all the work. `str_match_all` returns a list with each element a character matrix of matches and capture groups for each `df$text` value.
2. `map2` binds the `id`'s with the character matrices, so that each row refers to an `id` + `match` combination. The `if` statement checks if an element has no match and `rbinds` an NA value if it is the case. This allows `id` to have at least one row to bind to.
3. `mutate_at` converts each of the "capture_group" columns to dummy variables indicating whether "this capture group has a match"
4. Rename capture group columns with `rule_names` and transform all dummy into one single categorical variable.
5. Important note is that there is no way of knowing whether "5/6/2015" is MDYYYY or DMYYYY format, so in this case, you will have to order `patterns` to have one of them take precedence (e.g. if MDYYYY is before DMYYYY in `patterns`, MDYYYY will match first for "5/6/2015")

**Result:**

```
   id            string        rule
1   1         7/17/2015      MDYYYY
2   1              7/14    MD_slash
3   3           7/14/15        MDYY
4   3           10/5/15        MDYY
5   4           4/22/15        MDYY
6   4           5/12/15        MDYY
7   4           7/10/15        MDYY
8   4            7/8/15        MDYY
9   5           4/25/15        MDYY
10  5           5/22/15        MDYY
11  5          10-29-99        MDYY
12  5     Feb. 25, 2009 MDYYYY_word
13  6         4:30:2015      MDYYYY
14  6         5:22:2015      MDYYYY
15  6          1.3.1999      MDYYYY
16  6          09/26/99        MDYY
17  6            1.3.99        MDYY
18  6              7-14     MD_dash
19  7         6/30/2015      MDYYYY
20  7        09/26/1999      MDYYYY
21  7        30/06/2015      DMYYYY
22  8        2010-01-29      YYYYMD
23  8        2010-01-30      YYYYMD
24  8           4/25/15        MDYY
25  8           5/22/15        MDYY
26  8   February25,2009 MDYYYY_word
27  8 February 25, 2009 MDYYYY_word
```

Comment: I am not worried about the extraction or the regular expression. I would like to to know which rule lead to a particular extraction.

Comment: @x1carbon Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

### Brief

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe R does support PCRE regex. That being the case, you can use the following regex to catch any date in the formats you specified.

---

### Code

[See this regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/K3sHZL/1)

```
(?(DEFINE)
  (?# Definitions )
  (?<day>[12]\d|3[01]|0?[1-9])
  (?<month>1[0-2]|0?[1-9])
  (?<year>\d+)
  (?<separator>[.|\/:,-])
  (?# Date formats )
  (?<mdy>(?&month)(?<mdy_1>(?&separator))(?&day)(?&mdy_1)(?&year))
  (?<dmy>(?&day)(?<dmy_1>(?&separator))(?&month)(?&dmy_1)(?&year))
  (?<ymd>(?&year)(?<ymd_1>(?&separator))(?&month)(?&ymd_1)(?&day))
  (?<md>(?&month)(?<md_1>(?&separator))(?&day)(?&md_1)?)
  (?<dm>(?&day)(?<dm_1>(?&separator))(?&month)(?&dm_1)?)
  (?# Date )
  (?<date>(?&mdy)|(?&dmy)|(?&ymd)|(?&md)|(?&dm))
)
(?<=\b|\s)(?&date)(?=\b|\s)
```

---

### Explanation

The define block specifies all our definitions for what constitutes a *day*, *month*, *year*, *separator*. It also defines our date formats (*mdy*, *dmy*, *ymd*, *md*, *dm*). Finally it defines our *date* group which is a simple **OR** between all our date formats.

The final regex simply specifies that the preceding or following tokens should be word boundary characters `\b` or whitespace character `\s` (whitespace added here in the case of the last character being a word boundary character, it will catch the final character as well - you can test this with the first match by removing the `|\s` in the final regex to see the result).

Please note that this assumes the days of a month can go to 31 (a more specific check would result in a very lengthy regex and seems pointless when you can validate it through code).

---

### Results

#### Input

```
deficit based on wage statement 7/14/ to 7/17/2015.
Deficit Due: $1205.73 -$879.63= $326.10 x 70%=$228.2.
Deficit Due for 12 wks pd - 7/14/15 thru 10/5/15;Deficit due to wage,
statement: 4/22/15 thru 5/12/15,depos transcript 7/10/15 for 7/8/15 depos,
difference owed for 4/25/15-5/22/15 10-29-99 Feb. 25, 2009,
tpd 4:30:2015 - 5:22:2015--09/26/99, 7-14 1.3.99, 1.3.1999,
Medical TREATMENT DATES:  6/30/2015 -  30/06/2015 09/26/1999,
4/25/15-5/22/15,Medical 2010-01-29 **2010-01-30 February25,2009, February 25, 2009
```

#### Output

```
7/14/
7/17/2015
7/14/15
10/5/15
4/22/15
5/12/15
7/10/15
7/8/15
4/25/15
5/22/15
10-29-99
4:30:2015
5:22:2015
09/26/99
7-14
1.3.99
1.3.1999
6/30/2015
30/06/2015
09/26/1999
4/25/15
5/22/15
2010-01-29
2010-01-30
```

---

---

## Edits

### Code

[See this code in use here](https://regex101.com/r/K3sHZL/5)

```
(?(DEFINE)
  (?# Definitions )
  (?<day>[12]\d|3[01]|0?[1-9])
  (?<month>1[0-2]|0?[1-9])
  (?<year>\d+)
  (?<separator>[.|\/:,-])
  (?# Date formats )
  (?<f_mdy>(?&month)(?<mdy_1>(?&separator))(?&day)(?&mdy_1)(?&year))
  (?<f_dmy>(?&day)(?<dmy_1>(?&separator))(?&month)(?&dmy_1)(?&year))
  (?<f_ymd>(?&year)(?<ymd_1>(?&separator))(?&month)(?&ymd_1)(?&day))
  (?<f_md>(?&month)(?<md_1>(?&separator))(?&day)(?&md_1)?)
  (?<f_dm>(?&day)(?<dm_1>(?&separator))(?&month)(?&dm_1)?)
  (?<f_Mdy>(?:jan(?:uary|\.)?|feb(?:ruary|\.)?|mar(?:ch|\.)?|apr(?:il|\.)?|may|jun(?:e|\.)?|jul(?:y|\.)?|aug(?:ust|\.)?|sep(?:tember|\.)?|oct(?:ober|\.)?|nov(?:ember|\.)?|dec(?:ember|\.)?)\s*(?&day)(?:\s*(?&separator)|(?&separator)\s*|\s+)(?&year))
)
(?<=\b|\s)(?:(?<mdy>(?&f_mdy))|(?<dmy>(?&f_dmy))|(?<ymd>(?&f_ymd))|(?<md>(?&f_md))|(?<dm>(?&f_dm))|(?<Mdy>(?&f_Mdy)))(?=\b|\s)
```

This will set captures into named capture groups. If you look at the output in the link, you'll see named groups with the content it matched.

Comment: I am not worried about the extraction or the regular expression. I would like to to know which rule lead to a particular extraction.

Comment: The problem is some of these dates could match multiple formats. The only way to catch all these formats is to run the regex multiple times (one for each format), otherwise, if you want the first matching format, you can use the code in the edit. The named capture group is the format the date was found to be in. You can reorder the elements of the final regex so that, for example, *mdy* takes precedence over *dmy* or vice-versa.

Comment: This makes sense. A single extraction can be a result of multiple rules. Let me look at PCRE regex. Since there are multiple types of extractions like date extractions, holiday event extraction, season granularity etc. I thought it would make sense to put all the regex patterns in one data frame and loop through each rule against our text for final extraction. This would make the regex and it's extraction much more readable in the future.